# Non splitting sequence with free module

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory, modules

I am looking for a non splitting short exact sequence of modules $0 \rightarrow M_{1} \rightarrow M_{2} \rightarrow M_{3} \rightarrow 0$ where only $M_{1}$ (and only $M_{1}$) is free. Is it possible?

Also, the same question for $M_{2}$ (and only $M_{2}$) being free. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your restrictions are here to avoid things like the usual $0\to \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\to 0$, but you can just take the variant
$$0\to \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}\oplus A\to \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\oplus A\to 0$$
for any $A$ to answer your first question.

For the second one, you just need to take a non-principal ring. So for instance
$$0\to (n,X)\mathbb{Z}[X]\to \mathbb{Z}[X] \to \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\to 0$$
where the base ring is $\mathbb{Z}[X]$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. A pair of questions: why is $\mathbb{Z}\oplus A$ free?
And, what is the meaning of $(n,X)\mathbb{Z}[X]$?

Comment: Well, it is not. You wanted only $M_1$ to be free, so $M_1=\mathbb{Z}$ is free, and $M_2=\mathbb{Z}\oplus A$ is not. And by $(n,X)\mathbb{Z}[X]$ I mean the ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ generated by $n$ and $X$.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it bad, the thing is why is that module not free?

Comment: It is not free in general, of course it can be free if you choose some special $A$ ($A=0$ for instance). But if you take $A=\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ for instance, then $\mathbb{Z}\oplus A$ is not free since it has torsion.